# How to find the infinite sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)N+r}-\frac{1}{kN}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

How to find the infinite sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)N+r}-\frac{1}{kN}\right),$$
where $r,N$ are integers with $1\leq r\leq N$. When $N=2,r=1$, it is $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\cdots=\log2.$$ But the general case is remaining unknown. Does there are any method to solve the problem?

Comment: Equals $-\big(\gamma+\psi(r/N)\big)/N$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem) for an elementary expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_p=\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{(k-1) N+r}=\frac{\psi \left(p+\frac{r}{N}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{r}{N}\right)}{N}$$
$$T_p=\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{k N}=\frac 1 N\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{1}{k }=\frac{H_p}{N}$$ Using asymptotics of the digamma function and harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p}\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)N+r}-\frac{1}{kN}\right)=S_p-T_p=-\frac{\psi \left(\frac{r}{N}\right)+\gamma }{N}+\frac{r-N}{N^2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$